# Insert data in sql server with python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pypyodbc

I want to insert data in  the sql server from a raspberry pi with python.
I tried with pypyodbc but it s not working properly.
Can you guide me witch module to use.

```
import pyodbc 
conn = pyodbc.connect(
                     'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                     'SERVER=server;'
                     'Integrated_Security=false;'
                     'Trusted_Connection=no;'
                     'UID=pi;'
                     'PWD=pi;'
                     'DATABASE= database'
                 )
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM database.table')

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

> yodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', '[28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user \'pi\'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot open database " database" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060); [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user \'pi\'. (18456); [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot open database " database" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060); [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid connection string attribute (0)')

Comment: make sure in [sql server area configuration](https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/infinityinstaller/content/installermaster/tkenablenamedpipesandtcpipconnections.htm), connection via tcp/ip and named pipes are enabled.

Comment: @ManishMishra
I set up the sql server .
I am able to connect from a colleague computer with the sql credentials that i set up.
The server is visible from the outside everything seems fine from the server side.
the issue hat i have is that i cannot connect from pi via python.

Comment: well, the issue that you have pasted i.e. `Login failed for user \'pi\'`, says something wrong with access. Check if you can login via management studio through same credential, if yes, then its definitely named pipes access. Also make sure to restart your instance service for any changes

Comment: I see `server` is server and database is `database`. Are these correct? Anyway, remove space before `database` text. Check whether you are able to login using this connection details directly through SQL Server client.

Comment: @ManishMishra i can connect via ***.***.**.**\SQLEXPRESS on ssms with the credentials that sounds good to you?

Comment: @fiveelements i put that there so i won.t expose my server and data.

Comment: @Catalin there's no `Trusted_Connection` nor `Integrated_Security`. Using keywords at random will *guarantee* a failure. Either specify Windows Authentication or a username/password pair, not both

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you specify what do you mean about keyword at random?

Comment: @Catalin I already did. You used Integrated_Security *and* Trusted_Connection *and* UID *and* PWD in the same connection string. This guarantees that `Invalid connection string attribute` error. If you don't want to use Windows Authentication just use UID and PWD. The docs *aren't* wrong.

Comment: @Catalin speaking of docs, try the connection string shown at [Step 3: Proof of concept connecting to SQL using pyodbc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-2017#step-1--connect). The connection string uses the ODBC driver, not the (old) Native Client. Only UID and PWD are used to pass the credentials.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i found the issue

Comment: @Catalin, no, you are using \SQLExpress to connect via ssms, but `server` instance in your python code. you should use `.\SqlExpress` in your python code too

Comment: @ManishMishra now i am unable to install odbc driver 17 for sql server on debian 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a colleague just passed by me and told me to put all the data between '' only in 1 row
Also i removed  'Integrated_Security=false;'Trusted_Connection=no; as someone told me

The working code

```
something='something'
import pyodbc 
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=srv;DATABASE=datavase;UID=pi;PWD=pass')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("insert into test values (?, 'awesome library ')",var)
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM test')
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score -2):

I would highly recommend using sqlite3

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(
                      'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                      'SERVER=server;'
                      'Integrated_Security=false;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=no;'
                      'UID=pi;'
                      'PWD=pi;'
                      'DATABASE= database'
                  )
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM database.table')

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

Comment: the question is about using `sql server`. and not `what db server would you recommend?`

Comment: I use sqlite3 as backup if the network goes of. i want to be able to write in the database directly and in case the network is down to write in a local .db